# How to get the percentile from the dataset?

Tags: r

I processed the dataset.

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')

df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
```

Considering the new cases announced, the top 3 countries that explained the most cases explained what% of the total cases. can we find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this with Base R. Since the statistics are cumulative for each country by day, we subset to the most recent day's data with the `[` form of the extract operator, sort by descending confirmed cases, calculate and sum the percentages for the first 3 rows.

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv') 
df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
# subset to max(day)

today <- df[df$day == max(df$day),]
today <- today[order(today$confirmed,decreasing=TRUE),]
today$pct <- today$confirmed / sum(today$confirmed)
paste("top 3 countries percentage as of",today$day[1],"is:",
  sprintf("%3.2f%%",sum(today$pct[1:3]*100)))
```

...and the output:

```
> paste("top 3 countries percentage as of",today$day[1],"is:",
+       sprintf("%3.2f%%",sum(today$pct[1:3]*100)))
[1] "top 3 countries percentage as of 2020/05/30 is: 44.09%"
```

We can print selected data for the top 3 countries as follows.

```
today[1:3,colList]
        countryName        day confirmed        pct
26000 United States 2020/05/30   1816117 0.29531640
3640         Brazil 2020/05/30    498440 0.08105067
21710        Russia 2020/05/30    396575 0.06448654
>
```

Comment: hello, First of all, thank you for the answer.
'' Error in paste("top 3 countries percentage as of", today$day[1], "is:",  : 'today' nesnesi bulunamadı''. I'm getting an error.
why does this?

Comment: @BurakUnal - Did you run my entire script? The first few lines of code create a data frame called `today` that is required for the last line of code to work.